# Trying to understand linear state-space notation

Tags: time-series, state-space-models

I am trying to understand the state-space notation in [this paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3079909/). Specifically, it has the observation model as

[image]

and the state/dynamic model as

[image]

$y$ are the observations, $x$ and $z$ are possible covariates, and $L$ the autoregression lag.

My question is why does the mean, $\mu$, not enter the state-space equation? As it is specified, does this not indicate that the value of the state-space variable will generally be $\mu$ lower (if $\mu$ is positive). That is, if we are interested in making inference on the state variable $\theta$, it will generally be $\mu$ distance away.

Comment: I think you are right. But why be surprised about the setup?

Comment: @RichardHardy; I think my confusion is coming from is that for inference tasks, like $P(\theta \mid y)$, the aim is to estimate some underlying latent level. Given the way the model is specified then this value would always be biased by $\mu$. But I suppose there is nothing to stop me adding $\mu$ to $\theta$, ?

Comment: I think so. I am no expert, so I might be missing something, but this is what I think.

Comment: Thanks @RichardHardy; I appreciate your comments -- it is helpful to talk things through

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SSMs aren't always identifiable without restrictions on the parameter space. There is a common distinction between **centered** and **uncentered** parameterizations.

What you have written would be called the uncentered parameterization of this particular model. Generally this is when the observation equation is loaded up with more parameters. In this case, the latent state will have a marginal mean of $0$.

An equivalent centered parameterization would have the state equation as

$$
\theta_{t}   \mid \theta_{t-L:t-1} \sim \mathcal{N}\left(\mu + \sum_{l=1}^L\Phi_l\left(\theta_{t-l} - \mu\right) + \Delta z_t, \Sigma_{\eta}  \right)
$$
and an observation equation

$$
y_t \mid \theta_t \sim \mathcal{N}\left(\Psi\theta_t + \Gamma x_t, \Sigma_{\epsilon} \right).
$$
The marginal mean of $\theta_t$ is now $\mu$, if you write it like this.

Comment: Thanks Taylor, this is great. I appreciate some keywords here that gives me something to read up on.

Answer (score 1):

The intuition, I think, is that it wouldn't be identifiable.

A sketch of the argument: Add an intercept, call it $\mu_\theta$, to the equation for the expected value for $\theta_t$ in (1). Setting the first col/row/element of $\Psi$ to 1 for convenience, plug in this expected value to get the expectation of $Y_t$ conditional on $\theta_t$, and collect terms. $\mu$ and $\mu_\theta$ enter additively into the conditional expectation formula, but we don't have any way to distinguish them, so we can only really estimate the level shift $(\mu + \mu_\theta)$. Consequently, we can just set one of them to zero. Since $Y$ is observable, it will probably make more sense - although it doesn't really matter - to keep $\mu$ and interpret it like an regression intercept. However, you could keep $\mu_\theta$ in (1) instead, I guess.

Comment: Thanks conjugateprior. Identifiability of these models is something I am currently working through. One of things I was struggling with the above notation was that to me (and probably just me) it made more sense for the mean to be in the state variable, and then the observation model would just take a noisy sample (and so this way they have the same mean). But as you point out some of this notation is malleable and I suppose some decisions may be driven by how they are estimated.